# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection Error

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

**Could anybody tell me what is this error?**

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

I have a Service and IService like ITest.cs and TestRepository , I register its in start up class

```
services.AddScoped<ITest, TestRepository>();
```

I use a Mongodb in database .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I forget to register my generic classes

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(MongoDBRepository<>));
```